# Javascript escape global replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex replace:

```
referenceNode=referenceNode.replace(/\//g,"\/");
```

I want to replace `/` for `\/` for example. But , the `//` in the regex makes a comment in the javascript. How can I do this?

I put between `/     /g` because I want to replace in all string. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try storing `\/` in a variable and append it to regex.

Comment: How can I append it ? I can't call var exp = "\/" and then replace(/exp/g,...) :S Any idea? @noob

Comment: Why not use regex in capturing groups like this `/(?:\/)/g` . That will avoid `//` part.

Comment: No, no parser would interpret this `//` as a comment. Why do you think it does? However, you're replacing one forward slash with another forward slash. If you want to replace the forward slash with a backward slash followed by a forward slash, it would need to be `replace(/\//g, "\\/")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
referenceNode=referenceNode.replace(new RegExp("\\/", "g"),"\\/");
```

**Note:** The double backslash (`\\`) is for escaping the initial backslash character in a string.

**Another note:** The `new RegExp("\\/","g")` means the same as `/\//g`.

Comment: Your "Another note" is incorrect. `new RegExp("\\/")` means the same as `/\//`, not `/\\//g` which is a syntax error (or more precisely, it divides the regexp by the variable `g`). Also, please explain why the literal regexp the OP showed does not work.

Comment: Oh, yeah, got confused with the slashes :D already fixed. Also fixed the explanation part.

Comment: `/\//` does not create a comment, that is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Then edit the answer as you wish, I'm totally lost why it does work :P

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is fine; it's the replacement string that's wrong:

```
referenceNode = referenceNode.replace(/\//g, "\\/");
```

You need to escape the backslash because backslash is a meta-character in the string literal token grammar.

Comment: But the first '//' in the first expression made a comment in javascript

Comment: And thanks for the answer, this was wrong too. But the comment I can't solve.

Comment: @PRVS I assure you that `/\//` does not make a comment in JavaScript. I absolutely guarantee it. Go to your browser console and type `/\//.test("a/b")` and it will print out `true`.